# CGI::Session.pm file not present

Tags: perl, cgi, cpan

I'm working latest CGI module (version 4.3+) and when I try to create CGI:: Session objects in a pl file, it's throwing error saying Session.pm file not present. As it said Session.pm file is not existing in @INC. How come file missed and is there any fix for this.

Comment: Please provide the exact `use` statement and the exact error message. (Feel free to to replace private words in the paths with alternate words on a one-to-one basis.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [CGI::Session](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session) isn't installed on your system. It's a separate distribution to [CGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI), so it needs to be installed separately.

Comment: Downloaded the session module from the link you provided and pasted session folder contents to CGI folder. its working

Comment: @NirmalPraveen: That's a terrible approach. Please install CPAN modules using the standard methods.

Comment: in Perl package manager, I'm unable find session module. Is there any alternative way to do it.

Comment: I've no idea what a "Perl package manager" is. You should install CPAN modules using [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm).